# How to display formatted value as user types, but send the raw value to the Angular 4 formControl for validation and the formControl value?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular4-forms

I am new to Angular2/4.

I have an input field with formControlName = "Price", and I need the input value to be displayed in the correct currency format as the user types. When user types '100000', I need it to be displayed as 'Rp100,000' but the raw value should be sent as it is to the FormControl value.

I have tried sth like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPriceInput]'
})
export class PriceInputDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('ngModelChange')
  onValueChange($event) {
    let value = this.el.nativeElement.value;

    if (value.toLowerCase().indexOf('rp') !== -1) {
      value = this.onRemoveCurrencyPipe(this.el.nativeElement.value);
    }

    const formattedValue = new CurrencyPipe('en').transform(value, 'IDR', 'symbol-narrow', '1.0-0');
    this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(formattedValue);
  }

  @HostListener('blur')
  onBlur($event) {
    const rawValue = this.onRemoveCurrencyPipe(this.el.nativeElement.value);
    this.control.viewToModelUpdate(rawValue);
  }

  onRemoveCurrencyPipe(data) {
    return data
      .substr(2, data.length)
      .split(',')
      .join('');
  }
}
```

Here's the form group and the validations. The price should only be a string of number.

```
createMedicineForm() {
    this.medicineForm = this.fb.group({
      medicineName: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: [1, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$'), Validators.min(1)]],
      unit: ['tablet', Validators.required],
      price: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]],
      medicineId: ''
    });
  }
```

But the result is still wrong. It seems like the problem here is the wrong implementation of `this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(formattedValue)` and `this.control.viewToModelUpdate()`.

Anyone have any idea of the correct implementation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding correct currency format can be achieved  by using simple css as below

```
.price {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.price:before {
    content: "Rp";
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 75px;
}

.price> input {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Html will be

```
<div class="price">
Input here: <input type="text" formControlName="Price"/>
</div>
```

Depending on situation change the value of padding-left, left.